# Raw data: reading attributes with varied number of spaces in R

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to read in the Baylor dataset but I can't use read.csv since the spaces are not consistent.

I do have the column numbers so I was thinking read.fwf would help fix my issue but that means I have to review more than 100 attributes and check the line widths.

Is there an easier way to read the data?

```
baylor <- read.csv('C:/Users/Documents/baylor-religion-survey-data-2007.txt', header=F)
```

[Column Numbers](http://facweb.cdm.depaul.edu/sjost/csc433/projects/baylor-religion-survey-column-numbers.txt)
[Baylor Religion 2007 Survey Data](http://facweb.cdm.depaul.edu/sjost/csc433/projects/baylor-religion-survey-data-2007.txt)

Comment: You can try `readLines` and parse each line through and combination of `strsplit` and `trimws`...perhaps?

Comment: When I do this, `summary(sapply(df, function(x) {x <- gsub(' +', ' ', x); x <- strsplit(x, ' '); return(length(x[[1]]))}))` after reading the file with `readLines`, it is clear that each line has varying number of fields. So, you will need to parse out each line differently, I think. Unless, someone else has a trick up their sleeves.

Comment: better to programmatically process the column number info.  See my answer ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tested carefully, but I think this does it:

Define URLs:

```
lnum_url <- "http://facweb.cdm.depaul.edu/sjost/csc433/projects/baylor-religion-survey-column-numbers.txt"
survey_url <- "http://facweb.cdm.depaul.edu/sjost/csc433/projects/baylor-religion-survey-data-2007.txt"
```

Read file with column info:

```
nums <- read.table(url(lnum_url),as.is=TRUE,header=TRUE)
```

Extract starting column for each field:

```
startcol <- as.numeric( ## convert to numeric
      sapply(
          strsplit(nums[,3],"-"),  ## split strings on dashes
          "[",1))  ## select first element of each result
## sapply(z,"[",1)  == sapply(z,function(x) x[1])
```

Field widths are differences (assume last field is length 1):

```
w <- c(diff(startcol),1)
```

Read fixed width:

```
r <- read.fwf(url(survey_url),widths=w)
```

Assign field names:

```
names(r) <- gsub(":","",nums$COL)
```

Some quick checks:

```
str(r[,1:8])
## 'data.frame':    1648 obs. of  8 variables:
##  $ ID      : num  1.1e+09 1.1e+09 1.1e+09 1.1e+09 1.1e+09 ...
##  $ WEIGHT  : num  0.822 0.312 1.604 1.184 1.35 ...
##  $ REGION  : int  3 3 4 3 2 2 2 4 2 2 ...
##  $ RELIG1  : int  12 12 46 45 14 31 16 33 16 16 ...
##  $ RELIG2  : int  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
##  $ DENOM   : Factor w/ 301 levels "                                                   ",..: 231 231 1 1 1 1 83 113 1 23 ...
##  $ RELGIOUS: int  3 4 1 3 3 4 4 4 3 4 ...
##  $ ATTEND  : int  5 8 0 8 3 0 8 7 1 8 ...

tail(sort(levels(r$DENOM)))
## [1] "        RIVER OF LIFE EVANGELICAL FREE OF ELK RIVER"
## [2] "      ELCA - EVANGELICAL LUTHERAN CHURCH OF AMERICA"
## [3] "      WASHBURN CHRISTIAN CHURCH DISCIPLES OF CHRIST"
## [4] "    THE CHURCH OF JESUS CHRIST OF LATTER DAY SAINTS"
## [5] "   GENERAL ASSOCIATION OF REGULAR BAPTISTS CHURCHES"
## [6] "CONGREGATIONAL/METHODIST UNITED CHURCHES OF DURHAM,"
```

Some more processing (e.g. stripping white space in the denominations) might be in order, and I would certainly further check these results, but this should get you most of the way there.

For future reference it might be worth downloading the data from the [original download site](http://www.thearda.com/Archive/Files/Downloads/BAYLORW2_DL.asp) and checking cross-tabulations against the [code book](http://www.thearda.com/Archive/Files/Codebooks/BAYLORW2_CB.asp) ...

Comment: Hey I don't quite understand this line `as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(nums[,3],"-"),"[",1))` I can see that you are splitting by dash but what is the square bracket and 1 for?? Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know what the bracket was but after viewing your notes and also this sire [https://kbroman.wordpress.com/2013/08/20/and-with-the-apply-functions/] it helped clear things up